PHP Business SDK Request Issue: OpenSSL Error Connection reset by peer
Neither my server provider nor I could resolve this issue.
I am using CloudFlare Proxy and Flexible SSL Mode.
I'm having trouble with Facebook Conversion API requests.
For example, I usually get this error when I want to send a ViewContent request: (but sometimes it is successful)
FacebookAds\Exception\Exception #35
OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to graph.facebook.com:443

We set CloudFlare SSL mode to "Full" but I get "too many redirects" error.
The website works entirely with https.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
